# Aggregating with attribute($currentfeature) filter in QGIS

Tags: qgis, expression, filter, aggregate

Why doesn't the filter work (4th variable passed into the aggregate function) when I try to use in the field calculator an expression of this type:

```
aggregate('Layer', 'sum', "Field1" ,  "Field2" = attribute($currentfeature, 'Field2'))
```

It returns the total sum of `"Field1"` rather than applying the filter.
In the aggregate function, such a filter seems to be always true, while by itself, it works.

Is it not possible to use feature-based expressions with the aggregate function, or can it work if I modify the expression?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It turns out that the filter you are passing to the aggregate function always returns True for any feature.

```
"Field2"  = attribute( $currentfeature, 'Field2')
```

In other words, what you have at the left hand side of the condition is the same as you have on the right hand side.

**Why?**

Because `"Field2"` gets the value of field `Field2` for the current feature, and that's exactly what the `attribute` function will do, because you're asking for the value of the field called `'Field2'` (second parameter) for the current feature (first parameter: `$currentfeature`).

Keep in mind that the filter expression can only access fields and values from the referenced layer (`'Layer'` in your example) and not from the layer you're going to store results into.

So, you need to pass a filter that not always evaluates to `True`, or it will not make sense to pass it at all.

Example of valid filters (it would depend on your field values, of course):

```
"Field2" = 185
"Field2" = 'abc'
"Field2" = attribute( $currentfeature, 'Field3' )
"Field2" = "Field3"
```

Comment: So how could I aggregate with such a filter? For example obtaining the sum of all field 1 filtered for each value of field 2, like we can do with a sumif in excel, such as for example sumif(A$2:A$40,A2,B$2:B$40) that would be dragged down from line 2 to line 40.

Comment: If I get it well, you can achieve it using `sum("Field1","Field2")`. This calls the function sum for `Field1` grouped by `Field2` values. Note that in the original question, you were using `aggregate`, which is intended to get values from other layers, whereas sum(), count(), and the like, operate on the same layer.

Comment: Indeed, it does work. I had no inkling the sum function had group and filter components. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Replacing `$currentfeature` with `@parent` will produce the output you likely are looking for. So your aggregate command will become: `aggregate( 'Layer', 'sum', "Field1" ,  "Field2"  = attribute( @parent, 'Field2'))`, which allows you still aggregate based on another layer, but also filter based on the current layer you are accessing.